# Problems with fade in/out animation selector when scroll the gridview

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I'm having problems when scroll my gridview, 'cause the selector that highlight the selected cells are appearing in other cells too (for a while) just during the scrolling. This problems starts after I add a `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animations to this selector, but I really want to let the animation, in order to a smoother transition.

My adapter code to this grid is:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<Model> modelList;

    public GridAdapter(Context ctx, List<Model> modelList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.modelList = modelList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelList != null ? modelList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return modelList.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, viewGroup, false);

            holder.gridCell = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_cell);
            holder.cellSelected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cell_selected);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Model model = modelList.get(pos);

        holder.gridCell.setBackgroundResource(model.getBackId());
        holder.gridCell.setText(model.getLabel());

        if (model.isSelected()) {
            //fade In
            holder.cellSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grid_selector);
            holder.cellSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cellSelected.animate().setDuration(1000).alpha(1.0f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    holder.cellSelected.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    holder.cellSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            //fade out
            holder.cellSelected.animate().setDuration(1000).alpha(0.0f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    holder.cellSelected.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    holder.cellSelected.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    holder.cellSelected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            }).start();
        }

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView gridCell;
        TextView cellSelected;
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what I have to change to stop this incorrect showing of the selector in other cells (don't selected one.)?

Any sugestion?

**Note** - both fadeIn and fadeOut works to cells that have to be selected, the only problem is during the scroll, some cells that should be unselected for a little while are animated too.

**EDITED** - Actually I think the problem is when recycle the view on grid, but I don't know how resolve it yet. Please, that is the only thing missing on project.

Thanks